# UITableViewCell with UIButton is not scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have `UITableView`. Each `UITableViewCell` content `UIButton`. `UIButton's` frame is equal to `UITableViewCell's` frame. But scrolling is not working when I tapped on button and scroll, only when I tapped on space between cell's scrolling is working. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you add some code as well, that you are using for creating cell? Also try disabling user interaction of button./

Comment: why do you need buttons at all? Use the tableview delegate to recognize touches on the cells!

Comment: @rishi your suggestion about user interaction is right! thanks a lot! Can you post this as answer?

Comment: @RomanHouse - Done!!!and welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the user interaction of your button. Then it will not take the touch event and you will be able to scroll properly.

Comment: So... what are we gonna do with a button that has no click event? Do you really think that it is a good recommendation? 

Comment: With different use cases recommendations will be changed

Answer (score 0):

The button is not forwarding the touch to the cell.

The easiest solution would be to give the cell the appearance of a button and use the normal delegate methods.